# Unknown length and multiple requirements for input

Tags: c, arrays, input, struct, terminal

I'm working with a struct called objective, that consists of a char name with a max of 8000 characters (most of the time will be much smaller), an int id, an int duration and an array of ints called deps that can have between 0 and 9000 elements.
Here it is:

```
typedef struct {
unsigned long id, duration, dep [9000];
char name [MAXNAME];
}Objective
```

I have some functions to work with this struct, I can add one, can remove, can print, etc. 
I need to use the terminal to specify what I want to do, for example to add an objective i need to write on the terminal " add id "name" duration deps".
So this is where my problem begins, in the name of the objective, it has to be between " ", if not the command isn't valid. I'm also having trouble with deps array, it can have between 0 and 9000 elements so i never know how many there are, i have to put them into an array that will be the deps of the objective. I also can't put two spaces between arguments.
Some examples of input lines:

"add 1 "objective1" 20 2 3 4 5" - this adds an objective with id 1, name "objective1", duration 20 and deps 2, 3, 4 and 5

"add 1 objective1 20 2 3 4 5" - this is invalid because the name is not between " "

"add 1 "objective1" 20" - this adds an objective with id 1, name "objective1", duration 20 and with no deps

"remove 1" - removes objective with id 1

I have this from a previous work using fgets:

```
char input[82], col [6], na [80];    unsigned long a, b;
double c;


while(input[0] != 'q'){
  if(fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin)){
      if(input[0] == 'p' && input[1] == '\n' && input[2] == '\0'){
        list(matrix);
    }
    else if(input[0] == 'i' && input[1] == '\n' && input[2] == '\0'){
        carac(matrix);
    }
    else if((sscanf(input, "%c %lu %lu %lf\n", &input[0],
     &a, &b ,&c) == 4)){
        adds(a, b, c, matrix);
    }
    else if(input[0] == 'l' && (sscanf(input, "%*c %lu\n", &a) == 1)){
        printLine(a , matrix);
    }
    else if(input[0] == 'c' && (sscanf(input, "%*c %lu\n", &a) == 1)){
        printColumn(a , matrix);
    }
    else if(input[0] == 'z' && (sscanf(input, "%*c %lf\n", &c) == 1)){
        zero(c , matrix);
    }
    else if(input[0] == 'o' && input[1] == '\n' && input[2] == '\0'){
        sortLine(matrix);
    }
    else if(input[0] == 'o' && (sscanf(input, "%*c %s\n", col) == 1) && strcmp(col, "column") == 0){
        sortColumn(matrix);
    }
    else if(input[0] == 'w' && input[1] == '\n' && input[2] == '\0'){
        file(matrix);
    }
    else if(input[0] == 'w' && (sscanf(input, "%*c %s\n", na) == 1) ){
        newFile(na, matrix);
    }
} 
}
```

But in this case it has to be much different, the name between " ", unknown number of deps elements and spaces between arguments are making this really hard for me, does anyone have some advice on how I can do this or how can I solve one of the problems I listed above?

Comment: If you are working with a struct named `objective`, shouldn't you include it in your post code section?

Comment: @ryyker thank you i already added the code for my struct

Comment: For any application depending on user input, complexity (required to handle user input) is inversely proportional to controls imposed on user.  i.e. if there are 0 constraints on user, then complexity in application to process input goes to infinity. Suggestions to simplify: 1) Use a menu, or a series of menus and do not accept any option other than those you provide. 2) do not use a struct, use lists.  They are much easier to _add_ or _remove_ sections,

Answer (score 0):

First, a note about user input: I agree with @ryyker, try to come up with a format for user input that's easy for you to parse. Trying to to make input too flexible from the start will hinder you, while you should focus on the program's logic.
But maybe you're not the one who chose the format, so, moving along...

Your choice of defining a struct and using fgets() is not bad.
But you put everything in a single while() construct, which does not help you organize your code. I won't give you a full code, but only pointers on how you could organize it.

I suggest you separate:

1. Reading user input into a buffer.
2. Extracting commands from that buffer.
3. Checking that user input is correct.
4. Interpreting commands and executing program logic.

*Part 1:*
scanf() is not good, because you don't know how long the line will be.
Keep using fgets on a reasonably long buffer, e.g.:

```
char buf[1024];

// ...

/* Maybe you'll want to use something else than fgets()
 * later on. Encapsulate "reading from user" in a function. */
void read_user_input(char **buf, int size) {

    *buf = fgets(*buf, size, stdin);
}
```

*Part 2 & 3:*
Write small functions to extract tokens from the buffer,
and check that e.g. each of them is separated by a single space,
or that the user used quotes around the "name".

```
/* Return the index of the first character of the next token
 * in a string. Start searching from "idx".
 * Tokens are separated by spaces. */
int next_token(char *buf, int idx, const int size) {

    while (idx < size && is_whitespace(buf[idx])) {
        ++idx;
    }

    if (idx == size) {
        return -1; // no token here
    }
    else {
        return idx;
    }
}

// ...

int check_spacing(char *buf, int size) {

    /* Extract tokens, maybe fill struct Objective along
     * the way. */
    int idx = 0;

    while (idx < size) {
        int next_token_idx = next_token(buf, idx, size);

        if (next_token_idx - idx > 1) {
            // More than 1 space, not good!
        }
    }
}
```

*Part 4:*
You already did the job: adds(), printLine(), printColumn()...

Once you cut in neat little functions, it will be much easier to write your main loop:

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    const int size = 1024;
    char buf[size];

    Objective obj = null;

    // Read as long as the line is not finished.
    do {
        read_user_input(buf, size);
        // Check that tokens are valid
        // Build a struct Objective along the way
        // obj = ... ;
        // Also fetch the command: "add", "remove"...
    } while (! contains_newline(buf));

    // Now that you're confident user input is OK,
    // you can execute command happily
    if (strcmp(command, "add") == 0) {
        // Add an objective
    }
    else if (strcmp(command, "remove") {
        // Remove an objective
    }
    else if (strcmp(command, "i") {
        carac(matrix);
    }
    // etc.
}
```